# Restricting an interface to specific keys from a union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

I've got a union type listing some allowed keys :
`type AllowedKeys = "a" | "b";`

Somewhere else, I'm declaring an interface, and I want to restrict this interface to the allowed keys :

```
interface Interface {
  a: Something; // This is fine
  c: SomethingElse; // I want this to throw an error
}
```

How could I write this to enforce that the interface respects the allowed keys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with [interface](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/interfaces), because

> This is because interfaces in TypeScript are open ended. This is a vital tenet of TypeScript that it allows you to mimic the extensibility of JavaScript using interfaces.

basically you can always add new properties to an interface.

Instead, you can try

```
type AllowedTypes =  {
    "a" : string;
    "b": number ;
}

type AllowedKeys = keyof AllowedTypes;
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Can this be done with an object type instead ?

Comment: Yes! Thinking this way actually does allows me to achieve what I needed to do, thank you! I'll let the question open for now to see if someone comes up with a different approach, but this works.

Comment: glad it helps you

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need this to be an interface and you can use type instead consider doing this:

```
type AllowedKeys = "a" | "b";

export type TestType = {
    [key in AllowedKeys]: Something;
};
```

It will enforce you to use both of these keys in your type - not sure if that's something you want. For example:

This will throw an error:

```
const a: TestType = {
    a: 'asd',
    b: 'asd',
    c: 'asd'
}
```

This is fine:

```
const a: TestType = {
    a: 'asd',
    b: 'asd',
}
```

But this will throw an error too:

```
const a: TestType = {
    a: 'asd',
}
```

If you don't care if all allowed keys are used just use `?` in your type declaration:

```
export type TestType = {
    [key in AllowedKeys]?: string;
};
```

Comment: I did tried this route and it works if every key has the same type. In my case I need each key to have a different, specific type

Comment: Makes sense, this response is not suitable for your case then :)